# How to "anchor" an BoxLayout on top side inside an TabedPannel with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a BoxLayout inside TabbedPannel with a "height size fixed" and i want it to "anchor" at the top, so when i re-size the height of the GUI it follows the top part and open space at the bottom.

I tried a many ways to do it, like pos_hint, AnchorLayout, putting a widget at the bottom of everything, but i hasnt able to make it work.

[image]

So here is the code.

**Exemple.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class TabMain(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(TabMain, self).__init__(*args)
        self.ids["panel"]._tab_layout.padding = '-2dp', '-2dp', '-2dp', '-2dp'

class GuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TabMain()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuiApp().run()
```

**gui.kv**

```
<TabMain>
    TabbedPanel:
        id: panel
        size: root.width, root.height
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'bottom_mid'
        tab_width: self.size[0] / 1
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Robos"
            background_color: (48/255, 48/255, 48/255, 1) if self.state == 'down' else (88/255, 88/255, 88/255, 1)
            background_down: ""
            background_normal: ""
            TabbedPanel:
                do_default_tab: False
                tab_width: 115

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: "Solicitar"
                    TabbedPanel:
                        tab_pos: 'bottom_right'
                        do_default_tab: False
                        TabbedPanelItem:

                            text: "Solicitar"
                            AnchorLayout:
                                anchor_y: 'top'
                                BoxLayout:

                                    orientation: "vertical"
                                    spacing: 4
                                    padding: 4
                                    pos_hint: {'y': 1}

                                    BoxLayout:
                                        size_hint: 1, None
                                        height: 30

                                        Label:
                                            text: "Login"
                                            halign: "right"
                                        TextInput:
                                            multiline: False
                                            size_hint: 1.7 , 1
                                        Label:
                                            text: "Senha"
                                        TextInput:
                                            multiline: False
                                            size_hint: 1.7, 1
                                    BoxLayout:
                                        size_hint: 1, None
                                        height: 30
                                        Label:
                                            text: "Data Inicial"
                                        TextInput:
                                            multiline: False
                                            size_hint: 1.7, 1
                                        Label:
                                            text: "Data Final"
                                        TextInput:
                                            multiline: False
                                            size_hint: 1.7, 1
                                    BoxLayout:
                                        size_hint: 1, None
                                        height: 45
                                        Label:
                                            text: "Lembrar informações dadas pelo usuario"
                                            size_hint: None, 1
                                            width: 350
                                        CheckBox:
                                            size_hint: 0.3, 1
                                        Label:
                                            size_hint: 1.4, 1
                                        Button:
                                            text: "Iniciar"
                                            size_hint: 2, 0.90
                                    BoxLayout:
                                        size_hint: 1, None
                                        height:60
                                        orientation: "vertical"
                                        spacing: 0
                                        BoxLayout:
                                            size_hint: 1, None
                                            height: 30
                                            ProgressBar:
                                                value: 25
                                            Label:
                                                size_hint: 0.1, 1
                                                text: "25.0%"
                                        BoxLayout:
                                            valign: "top"
                                            size_hint: 1, None
                                            height: 30
                                            Label:
                                                size_hint: None, None
                                                text: "Alguma informação"
                                                size: self.texture_size
                                            Label:
                                            Label:
                                                size_hint: None, None
                                                text: "Parado"
                                                size: self.texture_size
                                            Label:
                                                size_hint: 0.1, 1
                                    BoxLayout:
                                        size_hint: 1, None
                                        height: 15


                        TabbedPanelItem:
                            text: "Relatorio"
                            Label:
                                text: "Banco de Dados"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` tries to use all the space it has been given, so it ends up with empty space that shows up at the top of the `BoxLayout`. To fix that, you can use `minimum_height`:

```
                        AnchorLayout:
                            anchor_y: 'top'
                            BoxLayout:

                                orientation: "vertical"
                                spacing: 4
                                padding: 4
                                pos_hint: {'y': 1}
                                size_hint: 1, None
                                height: self.minimum_height
```